# disk usage bar in win 7

Tags: c#, windows-7

I would like towrite files into a flash drive without changing the disk usage bar displayed in win 7 (using programming c#/other methods)

Is it possible?

If so, may you give me an example code to do this!
Thank you!

Comment: And I want to buy things but my bank account should not been changed.

Comment: More seriously, I suppose you could write to sectors that aren't in use but you would have no expectation that they would still contain the same data when you looked again. And how would you remember which sectors you wrote to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically files are just references to blocks of written flash memory. If you copy the file to the flashdrive and delete it its still there until it gets overwritten. If you somehow save the reference you can access it if the flash drive hasn't changed. I don't have a code sample, just wanted to give you a direction.